# ConcurrentModificationException when using stream with Maps key set

Tags: java, foreach, lambda, hashmap, java-stream

I want to remove all items from `someMap` which keys are not present in `someList`.
Take a look into my code:

```
someMap.keySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(v -> !someList.contains(v))
    .forEach(someMap::remove);
```

I receive `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`.
Why I faced this Exception given that the stream is not parallel?
What is the most elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

@Eran already [explained](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32580851/4856258) how to solve this problem better. I will explain why `ConcurrentModificationException` occurs.

The `ConcurrentModificationException` occurs because you are modifying the stream source. Your `Map` is likely to be `HashMap` or `TreeMap` or other non-concurrent map. Let's assume it's a `HashMap`. Every stream is backed by [`Spliterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Spliterator.html). If spliterator has no `IMMUTABLE` and `CONCURRENT` characteristics, then, as documentation says:

> After binding a Spliterator should, on a best-effort basis, throw `ConcurrentModificationException` if structural interference is detected. Spliterators that do this are called *fail-fast*.

So the `HashMap.keySet().spliterator()` is not `IMMUTABLE` (because this `Set` can be modified) and not `CONCURRENT` (concurrent updates are unsafe for `HashMap`). So it just detects the concurrent changes and throws a `ConcurrentModificationException` as spliterator documentation prescribes.

Also it worth citing the [`HashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) documentation:

> The iterators returned by all of this class's "collection view methods" are *fail-fast*: if the map is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove method, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.
>
> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: *the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs*.

While it says about iterators only, I believe it's the same for spliterators.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, but you may edit it to add solution that @Eran mentioned. It would be 100% satisfying for anyone having the same problem in the future.

Comment: @MariuszJaskółka, Eran answer is also here and other people will likely to see it as well. It's correct and I upvoted it. I can add a reference to his solution.

Answer (score 17):

You don't need the `Stream` API for that. Use `retainAll` on the `keySet`. Any changes on the `Set` returned by `keySet()` are reflected in the original `Map`.

```
someMap.keySet().retainAll(someList);
```

Comment: OK, it is good answer for my second question. But I still don't know why `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException` occures.

Answer (score 12):

Your stream call is (logically) doing the same as:

```
for (K k : someMap.keySet()) {
    if (!someList.contains(k)) {
        someMap.remove(k);
    }
}
```

If you run this, you will find it throws `ConcurrentModificationException`, because it is modifying the map at the same time as you're iterating over it. If you have a look at the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html), you'll notice the following:

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

This is what you are doing, the map implementation you're using evidently has fail-fast iterators, therefore this exception is being thrown.

One possible alternative is to remove the items using the iterator directly:

```
for (Iterator<K> ks = someMap.keySet().iterator(); ks.hasNext(); ) {
    K next = ks.next();
    if (!someList.contains(k)) {
        ks.remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11):

Later answer, but you could insert a collector into your pipeline so that forEach is operating on a Set which holds a copy of the keys:

```
someMap.keySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(v -> !someList.contains(v))
    .collect(Collectors.toSet())
    .forEach(someMap::remove);
```